# curl yaml file to read yaml contents and not html

Tags: curl, yaml

What is the difference between these two yaml files (ingress-example.yaml and example-ingress.yaml)?

Read yaml using curl https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube-site-examples/ingress-example.yaml as the output is yaml:

```
% curl https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube-site-examples/ingress-example.yaml
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: foo-app
  labels:
    app: foo
spec:
  containers:
    - name: foo-app
      image: 'kicbase/echo-server:1.0'
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: foo-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: foo
  ports:
    - port: 8080
---
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: bar-app
  labels:
    app: bar
spec:
  containers:
    - name: bar-app
      image: 'kicbase/echo-server:1.0'
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: bar-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: bar
  ports:
    - port: 8080
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: /foo
            backend:
              service:
                name: foo-service
                port:
                  number: 8080
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: /bar
            backend:
              service:
                name: bar-service
                port:
                  number: 8080
---
```

But not read yaml using curl https://k8s.io/examples/service/networking/example-ingress.yaml as the output is html:

```
% curl https://k8s.io/examples/service/networking/example-ingress.yaml           
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

How to just read (not about download) https://k8s.io/examples/service/networking/example-ingress.yaml using curl?

Comment: Maybe try curl's `-L` or `--location` option. The [man page](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-L) defines it as: "If the server reports that the requested page has moved to a different location (indicated with a Location: header and a 3XX response code), this option makes curl redo the request on the new place."